# Sending parametrs via PUT method

Tags: php, curl

i'm using [php-curl-class](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class)

I have a question about sending parameters via PUT method.

```
$array = array(
    'id' => $_REQUEST['id'],
    'name' => $_REQUEST['name'],
    'second_name' => $_REQUEST['second_name']
);

$curl = new Curl();
$curl->setHeader('Accept', 'text/json'); 
$curl->setBasicAuthentication('login', 'pass');
$curl->put('link');
```

I have an array which is getting GET/POST values. I need to send them with PUT method. How i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you with an example that shows you how I have done this.

```
    $url = "http://domain.com";

    $this->curl = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true);
```

I hope this helps you...